# Notice: Undefined index: is_deceased

Tags: contacts, error

I get this message whenever I edit a contact:

Notice: Undefined index: is_deceased in CRM_Contact_Form_Contact->preProcess() (line 216 of C:\Bitnami\civicrm-4.6.9-1\apps\civicrm\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Form\Contact.php).

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Thanks, Ian

Comment: I am seeing a variant of this: Notice: Undefined index: group in CRM_Contact_Form_Contact->postProcess() (line 880 of /var/www/website/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php). I can't log in at https://lab.civicrm.org/ ...

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to be worried about, though it is a minor bug.  The [code there](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6.9/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php#L216) happens to look for the value of `$defaults['is_deceased']` without checking to see if the `$defaults` array has a value with the key `is_deceased`.  Two things:

1. You might record an issue at https://issues.civicrm.org so it gets fixed.
2. You should probably turn off the error messages if this is a production site.  In the Drupal admin menu, go to Configuration, then under Development see Logging and Errors.  Select `none` under "Error messages to display" and save the configuration.  (This, by the way, is why a notice like this goes unnoticed.)

Comment: I saw that advice on another error. Can I assume that by turning this off i will not miss other error messages that may be important?

Comment: By turning this off, you and any other site admins won't see the errors on screen.  However, they will still be logged.  It's good to periodically check your Drupal and Apache/Nginx logs for issues like this.  The reason the default is to display the errors is that you probably want to see them while you're building the site.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now have identical copies on my Laptop and Desktop and feel confident with backup!...and no error messages. Thanks.